# Is it OK in Python OOP to initialize a class from the module it's contained in upon import

Tags: python, oop, module

I'm using Python 2.7

I would like to know if in Python OOP, it's OK to add code in the module level to initialize a class that is contained in the module.

```
class DoSomething(object):

    foo = 0
    bar = 0

    @classmethod
    def set_all_to_five(cls):
        cls.bar = 5
        cls.foo = 5

    @classmethod
    def set_all_to_ten(cls):
        cls.bar = 10
        cls.foo = 10


#Module level code - runs on import of the class DoSomething
DoSomething.set_all_to_five()
```

Output:

```
>>> from productX.moduleY import DoSomething
>>> print DoSomething.bar
5
```

The class contains only @classmethod methods, so I can call them without having to instantiate the class.

The module level `code DoSomething.set_all_to_5()` Initializes the class level properties when the module is imported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [Is it] OK to add code in the module level to initialize a class that is contained in the module?

Yes, what you have is fine.  This is what the word ["dynamic"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#DYNAMIC) means when people describe Python as a dynamic language: **you may alter the definition of a type at runtime**.  The entire module in which the class is defined must import successfully before the `DoSomething` name can be used, so it is not possible for someone to accidentally use an "unpatched" version of the class.

However, should you want the behaviour of the class to be entirely defined within the class block, rather than applying a "monkeypatch" after the class definition, you have some other options available.

Using a **metaclass**:

```
class DoSomethingMeta(type):

    def __init__(self, name, bases, attrs):
        super(DoSomethingMeta, self).__init__(name, bases, attrs)
        self.set_all_to_five()


class DoSomething(object):

    __metaclass__ = DoSomethingMeta  # for Python3, pass metaclass kwarg instead

    foo = 0
    bar = 0

    @classmethod
    def set_all_to_five(cls):
        cls.bar = 5
        cls.foo = 5

    @classmethod
    def set_all_to_ten(cls):
        cls.bar = 10
        cls.foo = 10
```

Or, more simply, by using a **decorator**:

```
def mydecorator(cls):
    cls.set_all_to_five()
    return cls

@mydecorator
class DoSomething(object):
    ....
```

Comment: thanks. This is the reply I was hoping for. Thanks for the additional info on __metaclass__. In my case, I use the module level code to initialize the class with some data that is available only in runtime.